# How do I reset my pypi.python.org password on my PC

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I reset my [pypi.python.org](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) password?

I just reset my password on the [pypi.python.org](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) website and now I can not register/upload distribution from my command prompt because it keeps giving me a `401 basic auth failed` error

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks...Trevor, I was told to update the .pyirc but I don't know where to find the .pyirc or how to access it

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update your password in your [.pypirc](http://docs.python.org/distutils/packageindex.html#the-pypirc-file) file which is located in your home directory. You can edit it with the following command:

```
$ nano ~/.pypirc
```

If you prefer another editor to `nano`, just replace it with your editor of choice.